# Fillna in pandas using another pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here's my inital dataset

```
sitename            L1        L2         L3
America      Continent       NaN     Others
Mexico             NaN   Spanish    America
```

This is reference dataset

```
sitename            L1        L2
America        Country   English
Mexico         Country   Spanish
```

This is expected output dataset

```
sitename            L1        L2         L3
America      Continent   English     Others
Mexico         Country   Spanish    America
```

The reference data is only works on Null vales

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For align by column `sitemap` convert it to index in both DataFrames and then replace missing values:

```
df = df1.set_index('sitemap').fillna(df2.set_index('sitemap')).reset_index()
```

Or:

```
df = df1.set_index('sitemap').combine_first(df2.set_index('sitemap')).reset_index()
```

Or:

```
df1 = df1.set_index('sitemap')
df2 = df2.set_index('sitemap')
df1.update(df2)
df = df1.reset_index()
```

Comment: Why .update make df1 becoming `NoneType`

Comment: @NabihBawazir - seems used `df1 = df1.update(df2)`, so `None` in `df1`, because `update` working inplace. Co cannot assign to `df1`. Use only `df1.update(df2)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the:

```
df.fillna(df2)
```

If indexes are not the same, you can set them to be the same and use the same function:

```
df = df.set_index('sitname')
df.fillna(df2.set_index('sitename'))
```

Comment: second part is same like my answer.